# Rails params should read an array

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

My question is quite simple, I have a plain HTML form (no helpers, no models) and I want to send the parameters so params dictionary appears to be an array.

This is my code:

```
<div class="headers_line">
  <div class="header_field">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Header name" name="header[0][name]" class=
    "parameter_input" />
  </div>

  <div class="header_field">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Value" name="header[0][value]" class=
    "parameter_input" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="headers_line">
  <div class="header_field">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Header name" name="header[1][name]" class=
    "parameter_input" />
  </div>

  <div class="header_field">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Value" name="header[1][value]" class=
    "parameter_input" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="headers_line">
  <div class="header_field">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Header name" name="header[2][name]" class=
    "parameter_input" />
  </div>

  <div class="header_field">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Value" name="header[2][value]" class=
    "parameter_input" />
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is what my params looks like:

```
"header"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"jnjnnj", "value"=>"nnjjn"}, "1"=>{"name"=>"jnnjjn", "value"=>"jnjnnj"}, "2"=>{"name"=>"jnjnjnjn", "value"=>"jnnj"}, "3"=>{"name"=>"", "value"=>""}}
```

Trying to use header[][name] and header[][value] didn´t work either.

Thanks

Comment: Almost, it generates an array of names and another of values, but it's better: "header"=>{"name"=>["ijijjijijij", "ijadsijdasij", "adsadjsiiadjsjidsa", "jidadisjajdisai", ""], "value"=>["ijsijdsaijadsij", "ijdasjidasijij", "jadisidjsajidsaji", "sajidsji", ""]}

Comment: are you trying to flatten the hash to get rid of the "0","1" keys etc? is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve: params[:header] to be an array of {name: '2323', value: '123'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on @house9 comment I did the following:

I used `header[name][]` and `header[value][]`

Then I created an array of hashes by doing:

```
headers = params[:header][:name].zip(params[:header][:value])
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I was totally confused in the previous answer.

`params[:header].values.map(&:symbolize_keys)` will give you the array you want.

You cannot get it directly.